# Adding Image to Table View Javafx

Tags: java, image, javafx, tableview

I want to add a Image into a Table View Cell. I have the path to the photo but don't know exactly how to make the image show up in the Table.
Table:

```
ArrayList<Box> list1 = (ArrayList<Box>)service.listBox();

 ObservableList<Box> l = FXCollections.observableList(list1);

 tableViewBox.getItems().setAll(l);

 tableColumnBoxNr
   .setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Box, Integer>(
  "boxNr"));
  tableColumnPreis
    .setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Box, Float>(
  "preis"));
  tableColumnGroesse
    .setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Box, Integer>(
  "groesse"));
  tableColumnInnen
    .setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Box, Boolean>(
  "innen"));
  tableColumnFenster
.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Box, Boolean>(
  "fenster"));
  tableColumnMaterial
.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Box, String>(
  "material"));
  tableColumnEinstreu
    .setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Box, String>(
  "einstreu"));
  tableColumnPhoto
.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Box, String>(
  "photo"));
```

Here is how "Box" looks like:

```
private int boxNr;
private float preis;
private int groesse;
private boolean innen;
private boolean fenster;
private String einstreu;
private String material;
private String photo;
```

The path to the image is stored in `private String photo` and I would like that image to show up in the table. At the moment it simply shows the path.

Tried the link in the comments and the code looks like this:

```
public void eineMethode() {
 try {

   ArrayList<Box> list1 = (ArrayList<Box>)service.listBox();

   ImageView imageview = new ImageView();


     imageview.setFitHeight(50);
     imageview.setFitWidth(50);
     imageview.setImage(new Image("sepm.ss14.e1103974.gui/Pferdebox.jpg"));


     tableColumnPhoto.setCellFactory(new Callback<TableColumn<Box,ImageView>,TableCell<Box,ImageView>>()
       {

 @Override
 public TableCell<Box, ImageView> call(
   TableColumn<Box, ImageView> arg0) {
  TableCell<Box,ImageView> cell = new TableCell<Box,ImageView>(){

   public void updateItem(Box box, boolean empty) {
    if(box!=null) {
     VBox vb=new VBox();
     //vb.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
      ImageView imageview = new ImageView(new Image("/SEPM2014/src/sepm/ss14/e1103974/gui/Pferdebox.jpg"));


            imageview.setFitHeight(50);
            imageview.setFitWidth(50);
            vb.getChildren().addAll(imageview);
            setGraphic(vb);
    }
   }
  };
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  return cell;
 }

       });


   ObservableList<Box> l = FXCollections.observableList(list1);

   tableViewBox.getItems().setAll(l);

  tableColumnBoxNr
.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Box, Integer>(
  "boxNr"));
  tableColumnPreis
.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Box, Float>(
  "preis"));
  tableColumnGroesse
.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Box, Integer>(
  "groesse"));
  tableColumnInnen
.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Box, Boolean>(
  "innen"));
  tableColumnFenster
.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Box, Boolean>(
  "fenster"));
  tableColumnMaterial
.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Box, String>(
  "material"));
  tableColumnEinstreu
.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Box, String>(
  "einstreu"));
  tableColumnPhoto
.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Box, ImageView>(
  "photo"));
  tableViewBox.getColumns().setAll(tableColumnBoxNr,
   tableColumnPreis, tableColumnGroesse, tableColumnInnen,
tableColumnFenster, tableColumnMaterial,
tableColumnEinstreu, tableColumnPhoto);

  //tableViewBox.getItems().setAll(list1);
 } catch (Exception e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
 }
}
```

Still not working and getting Invalid URL error and furthermore I am unsure how to add the Image itself to the table as in my actual code I am adding the ObservableList "l" to the table. 
Help would be very much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16341583/placing-an-image-into-a-javafx-2-table

Comment: @AKS I changed the code and edited my post. Still unable to figure it out.

Comment: Ref this blog:- http://blog.ngopal.com.np/2011/10/01/tableview-cell-modifiy-in-javafx/